# How do I block a Keyerror in Python from reoccurring or create exception to handle it?

Tags: api, dataframe, exception, error-handling

Im new to Python and working with API,

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import datetime

threedaysago = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-3).strftime("%F")
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sendgrid.com")
payload = "{}"

keys = {
#    "CF" : "SG.UdhzjmjYR**.-",
}
df = []  # Create new Dataframe

for name, value in keys.items():
    headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer " + value }

    conn.request("GET", "/v3/categories/stats/sums?aggregated_by=&start_date={d}&end_date={d}".format(d=threedaysago), payload, headers)

    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

    d = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    c=d['stats']
#    row = d['stats'][0]['name']
    # Add Brand to data row here with 'name'
    df.append(c)  # Load data row into df
#1    
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0])
df_new = df[['name']]
df_new.rename(columns={'name':'Category'}, inplace=True)
df_metric =pd.DataFrame(list(df['metrics'].values))
sendgrid = pd.concat([df_new, df_metric], axis=1, sort=False)
sendgrid.set_index('Category', inplace = True)
sendgrid.insert(0, 'Date', threedaysago)
sendgrid.insert(1,'BrandId',99)
sendgrid.rename(columns={
                       'blocks':'Blocks',
                       'bounce_drops' : 'BounceDrops',
                       'bounces': 'Bounces',
                       'clicks':'Clicks',
                       'deferred':'Deferred',
                       'delivered':'Delivered',
                       'invalid_emails': 'InvalidEmails',
                       'opens':'Opens',
                       'processed':'Processed',
                       'requests':'Requests',
                       'spam_report_drops' : 'SpamReportDrops',
                       'spam_reports' : 'SpamReports',
                       'unique_clicks' : 'UniqueClicks',
                       'unique_opens' : 'UniqueOpens',
                       'unsubscribe_drops' : 'UnsubscribeDrops',
                       'unsubscribes': 'Unsubscribes'
                       }, 
                 inplace=True)
```

When I run this however, I receive an error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

I know the reason this happens is because there are no stats available for three days ago:

```
{"date":"2020-02-16","stats":[]}
```

But how do I handle these exceptions in my code because this is going to run as a daily report and it will break if this error is not handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"` means there is no column called `name` in your dataframe.

But, you believe that error occurred because of `"stats" : []`. It is also not true. If any of the indexes is empty the error should occur as `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

I have **recreated** this problem and I will show you to get an idea to overcome this problem.

- **Recreating `KeyError: "None of [Index(['name'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`**

```
import pandas as pd

df = [{'A': [1,4,5], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C':['a','b','c']}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0])
df = df[['D']]

print(df)
```

**Output -:**

```
KeyError: "None of [Index(['D'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

**Solution -:** You can see there is no column called 'D' in the data frame. Therefore, recheck your columns

---

- **Adding 'D' and see what happens**

```
import pandas as pd

df = [{'A': [1,4,5], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C':['a','b','c'], 'D': []}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df[0])
df = df[['D']]

print(df)
```

**Output -:**

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

**Solution -:** column 'D' need to fill same data count as 'A', 'B', and 'C'

---

- **Overcome from those two problems**

```
import pandas as pd

df = [{'A': [1,4,5], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C':['a','b','c'], 'D':[]}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df[0], orient='index')
df.transpose()

print(df)
```

**Output -:**

```
      0     1     2
A     1     4     5
B     4     5     6
C     a     b     c
D  None  None  None
```

You can see columns are now represented as rows. You can use `loc` to select each row column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = [{'A': [1,4,5], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C':['a','b','c'], 'D':[]}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df[0], orient='index')
df.transpose()

df = df.loc[['A']] # uses loc

print(df)
```

**Output -:**

```
   0  1  2
A  1  4  5
```